# When $p\in X\times Y$, is there a rule that allows us to infer $p=(p_x,p_y)$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, definition

For $p\in X \times Y$, is there a inference rule that allows us to say that $p=(p_x,p_y)$ for some $p_x\in X, p_y\in Y$?

For context, I am reading Pinter's "A Book of Set Theory" and couldn't find a clear inference rule.

I have tried using proof by contradiction to get the desired result, but I get a bit stuck as shown.

Edit: Some definitions used in the text

- $X\times Y  = \{ (x,y) \mid x\in X\wedge y\in Y\}$
- $(x,y)= \{\{x\},\{x,y\}\}$

[image]

Comment: What is your definition of $X\times Y$?

Comment: @SeverinSchraven $X\times Y={(x,y)| x\in X\wedge y\in Y}$

Comment: Sorry, I mean to put brackets around the stuff on the right hand side of the equal sign.

Comment: Right, but then by definition for every element in $p\in X\times Y$ there exists $x\in X$ and $y\in Y$ such that $p=(x,y)$.

Comment: Ah, I am sorry, you are looking for a formal proof.

Comment: If $\{(x,y) \mid x \in X \land y \in Y\}$ is a formal term, then the only thing it can really mean is $p \in \{(x,y) \mid x \in X \land y \in Y\} \iff (\exists x) (\exists y) p = (x,y) \land x \in X \land y \in Y$, and there's nothing to really prove. In ZF we would probably just directly define $X \times Y = \{p \in P(P(X \cup Y)) \mid (\exists x) (\exists y) p = (x,y) \land x \in X \land y \in Y \}$, where $P(a)$ is the power set of $a$.

Comment: (For visible curly braces in MathJax, use `\{` `\}`.)

Comment: @aschepler, is there a particular reason why we need to state that p is in the power set as you describe? Couldn't you just keep it as just p on the left side of the '|'?

Comment: The ZF axiom schema of specification requires a known superset of the desired set. This avoids issues like Russel's paradox: if we can write $S = \{x \mid x \notin x\}$ then this implies both $S \in S$ and $S \notin S$, so our set theory is not consistent.